# Move to end of line after typing autopaired quotes

Tags: textmate

When I use TextMate I often use ⌘↩ after typing autopaired quotes to move the caret to the end of line, and insert a carriage return.

However I want to move the caret to the end of the line, and exclude the carriage return.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd> is a default Mac OS X key binding. It's a good idea to learn [as many as you can](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html).